# How can I get user input with line breaks

Tags: python, input, line-breaks

When I do something like

```
userInput = input("Type in text")
```

and type in a piece of text like

```
"""
Line
Break
"""
```

that I copied from somewhere, the python console only assigns gets the first line, and then the next lines end up as the console thinking I'm trying to find a variable, with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Break' is not defined
```

as an error message. How would I get all the user input?

Comment: How would it know when the user has finished inputting text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print "ENTER STUFF:"
user_input="\n".join(iter(raw_input,""))
```

I guess ...

Comment: Yeah... not sure what should happen if the OP wants a deliberately blank line inside what looks like a triple quoted string :)